# Motorola BarCode scan not working

Tags: c#, device, motorola, motorola-emdk

I am trying to write a small application to read BarCode using Motorola MC5040 Symbol device. Clicking on a button on form should read BarCode.
I am having hard time finding any sample projects. I reference Symbol and Symbol.Barcode DLLs
Here is the code that is not working. Not sure how to control the side buttons on device either.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static Symbol.Barcode.Reader SymbolReader = new Reader();
    public static Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData SymbolReaderData = new ReaderData(ReaderDataTypes.Text, 100);
    public static System.EventHandler SymbolEventHandler = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitScanner();
    }

    public void InitScanner()
    {
        SymbolEventHandler = new EventHandler(this.SymbolReader_ReadNotify);
        SymbolReader.Actions.Enable();
    }

            public void SymbolReader_ReadNotify(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SymbolReader.Actions.Enable();
        Symbol.Barcode.ReaderData TheReaderData = SymbolReader.GetNextReaderData();
        if (TheReaderData.Result == Symbol.Results.SUCCESS )
        {

                txtBarcode.Text = TheReaderData.Text.ToString();
                SymbolReader_CycleScannerReader();
                return;

        }
        SymbolReader_CycleScannerReader();
    }

    public void SymbolReader_CycleScannerReader()
    {
        SymbolReader.Actions.Read(SymbolReaderData);
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      SymbolReader_ReadNotify(sender,  e);
    }    
 }
}
```

Any pointers or correction will be great.

Comment: Have you tried EMDK.NET samples? Also, there's DataWedge in MC devices, make sure it's turned off before trying to use barcode programmatically.

Comment: Didn't find any sample in SDK I found :(. How to turn off DataWedge ?

Comment: Have you checked C:\Program Files (x86)\SAMPLES08 folder? I downloaded EMDK.NET 2.9 for it https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Resolution?solutionId=97036&productDetailGUID=f5563b1ca4151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD&detailChannelGUID=a0bde8cea8151410VgnVCM10000001c7b00aRCRD

Comment: Somewhere in Settings there should be DataWedge configuration app where you can turn it off. Not really sure where it will be located since my experience with MC Devices are different series in my previous job.

Comment: Thanks alot. Found Sample05 and a sample app is working. I am starting to look further.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample application using the Symbol.Barcode2 library
https://github.com/bigfont/2013-128CG-Vendord/blob/master/HelpfulStuff/CS_Barcode2Sample1/API.cs

if you initialize a `Barcode2` object you can then use that object to capture scan data

```
var myBarcode2Obj = new Barcode2();
myBarcode2Obj.OnScan += //Your scan even here;
```